# Height of FCC arrangement

Tags: crystal-structure, atomic-radius, bravais-lattices

I have read that height of HCP arrangement is given by $\mathrm{4r\sqrt{\frac23}}$ as distance between consecutive layers is $\mathrm{2r\sqrt{\frac23}}$(in both FCC and HCP). If that is the case, then what is the height of FCC arrangement? Can it be $\mathrm{3r\sqrt{\frac23}}$? I highly doubt that FCC is an "abc" arrangement and not "ab" arrangement.
(r=radius of sphere)

Answer (score 2):

My first instinct was to say that FCC has no height, because that's a cubic cell and it only has one parameter.

Then again, you didn't ask about the *cell*. The question was about the FCC *arrangement*, and as such, it makes perfect sense (if maybe in imperfect wording, as "height" is not quite the word to be used here). What is the "vertical" distance from a layer to the next layer with identical placement, really?

Well, it is as simple as that: like you said, HCP is a two-layer packing, hence its height is twice the distance between the layers. On the other hand, FCC (when thought of in terms of hexagonal layers) is a three-layer packing, hence its "height" is **three times the distance between the layers**. You also said that the distance between the adjacent layers is $2\sqrt{2\over3}r$, which is correct.

See where this is going?